# How can I convert .mp4 files to .3gp using ffmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg, codecs, convert

I would like to download a few videos from youtube and convert them to 3gp so that I can play them on my phone. I would like to know how this can be done using ffmpeg.

I tried the various results on the net only to get the following errors.

1. I used:

   ```
   ffmpeg -i dil.mp4 -sameq -ab 64k -ar 44100 dilenada.3gp
   ```

I got:

```
Unsupported codec for output stream #0.1
```

Seems stream 0 codec frame rate differs from container frame rate: 2000.00 (2000/1) -> 29.92 (359/12)

1. I used:

   ```
   ffmpeg -y -i dil.mp4 -r 20 -s 352x288 -b 400k -acodec libfaac -ac 1 -ar 2000 -ab 24k dilenada.3gp
   ```

I got:

```
Seems stream 0 codec frame rate differs from container frame rate: 2000.00 (2000/1) -> 29.92 (359/12)

Unknown encoder 'libfaac'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You would be best to lose the -sameq option which [rarely accomplishes what you think it does](http://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Option%20%27-sameq%27%20does%20NOT%20mean%20%27same%20quality%27).....

Answer (score 12):

Use the following command:

```
ffmpeg  -y -i movie.mp4 \
        -r 20 -s 352x288 -vb 400k \
        -acodec aac -strict experimental -ac 1 -ar 8000 -ab 24k \
        movie.3gp
```

Comment: Would have been nice, if you could explain it.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You probably just need to install the non free/restricted packages of ffmpeg like `libavcodec-extra-53 libavformat-extra-53 libavutil-extra-51` and the likes.

Calling ffmpeg with `--list-encoders` will show the available encoders.

Comment: I tried installing them but still the commands mentioned in the question did not work.

Comment: Still the same error messages?

Answer (score 1):

You are doing everything right :).
You will have to install for the conversion to work.

> Ubuntu Restricted Extras, i.e.  libavcodec-extra-53

You may get it from the software center or use the following command

> sudo apt-get install ffmpeg libavcodec-unstripped-52

Comment: Also check this out http://www.catswhocode.com/blog/19-ffmpeg-commands-for-all-needs

Answer (score 1):

I ran into problems with ffmpeg too

Apparently, ubuntu is no longer using ffmpeg, but a fork called avconv. This makes some (many ?) commands found on sites unusable on ubuntu.

What I did was just get the original ffmpeg:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:jon-severinsson/ffmpeg
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ffmpeg
```

not sure how much this would help you, though

Comment: your line is not working here, but at least it is not giving the "unknown codec" error, but one about resolution

Answer (score 0):

In order to get round this problem, the only option may be to `build from source`. That solved any issues for me. I uninstalled any of the `ffmpeg` packages currently on the system that I had tried to use, and [used this excellent Ubuntu compilation guide](http://ffmpeg.org/trac/ffmpeg/wiki/UbuntuCompilationGuide). This was the only way I could encode to proprietary formats such as mp4 and mp3.

In addition, the following script, which I have modified (credit to the original creator), can again be further altered and used to convert `mp4 to 3gp` or `mp4 to mp3` (to extract the audio), or anything whatsoever. It also preserves the original name of the file in the newly converted file: It is however important to fill in the options correctly.

You can use different options for 3gp; for example,you may want a different resolution than `qcif` (176x144), but I found these settings initially worked for me with my `compiled` version of `ffmpeg`. (The conversion may take a while, depending on how powerful your CPU is, as converting it to 3gp reduces the file size quite a lot: 314mb to 13 mb for one of my conversions!)

Save this script below to a new document and make it executable (`chmod +x`), place it in the desired folder and execute it; or use the terminal to select the folder the script is in and the target folder containing the files; e.g. `~/Scripts/script ~/Downloads`

```
#!/bin/bash
for f in *.mp4
do
    name="${f/.mp4/.3gp}"
    ffmpeg -i "$f" -vcodec h263 -s qcif -r 15 -b 100k -acodec libfaac -ac 1 -ar 32000 -ab 64k -f 3gp "$name"
done
```